# Google Knowledge Graph API Error

Tags: api, google-knowledge-graph

I can't find an official support page or point of contact for this Google API and the contact page suggests I should post to StackOverflow so here I go.

Within the last hour or so, I've been getting this error from all of my Google KG Search requests:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

My API key is still valid and the developer's console is logging the errors. I have a handful of test commands I've put in that have worked as of last Friday. I have also used the official API explorer web interface with no such luck. (See: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/knowledge/kgsearch/v1/kgsearch.entities.search)

Has anyone else used this API before or are currently experiencing this issue?

Comment: Oops, I just posted a dupe here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45556863/kbsearch-outage-returning-invalid-argument

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue is with Google Api this morning, but it is working now, Just tested the API and is working as it worked like previous without any changes.