# kbsearch outage - returning INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: google-api, google-knowledge-graph

I've been using the Knowledge Graph API for a few months now.  I just received a 400 "Request contains an invalid argument".  I believe the API is having an outage or undocumented new requirement.

Here are instructions:
https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/#sample_request

Here is a more specific example per the instruction.  My API key is correct.  Using an intentionally invalid API key produces an appropriate error.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/kgsearch/v1/kgsearch.entities.search?indent=true&limit=1&query=taylor+swift&_h=4&

Exact query URL would be:
https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=taylor+swift&key={api-key}&limit=1&indent=True

---

**Update:** It just started working again.